# Unable to conditionally execute if block in Python

Tags: python

I am assigning the value of a system environment variable. Based on the value of this variable - true or false, I have the if and else block to be executed. 
When the value of that variable is false, it is executing the else block successfully, but if the value of the variable is true, then it is not executing the statements in the if block.

Code snippet is :

```
propDictionary = globals()
isMtEnabled = propDictionary['convertToMt']

 if isMtEnabled == "true" :
                if props.getProperty("ClusterName") != None and props.getProperty("ClusterName") != "" :
                        print "Have a cluster"
                        clusterNames = clusterName1.split()
                        print "clusterNames is "
                        print clusterNames
                        targetMBeans = []
                        for clusterName in clusterNames:
                                storeName='WseeFileStore_'+clusterName
                                addNamedFileStoreOnServer (storeName,clusterName,distPolicy="Distributed")
 else :
                counter = 0
                c1_arr = []
                c2_arr = []
                for serverName in serverList:
                        if serverName.startswith("c1"):
                                storeName='WseeFileStore_'+serverName
                                addNamedFileStoreOnServer(storeName,serverName,distPolicy="Distributed")
                                jmsServer = addJMSServer(serverName,storeName=storeName)
```

When I do a print of isMtEnabled variable, it will print either true or false.
When its value is true, it should execute the if block but instead its not entering the if block at all.

What could be possibly wrong in this case ?

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code. Python is sensitive to indentation which makes proper formatting crucial.

Comment: Format your code please!

Comment: Is `isMtEnabled` really a string?

Comment: True and "true" are not the same thing. If you want to check whether something has a boolean value of True you have to use something == True, not "true".

Answer (score -1):

Can you print `type(isMtEnabled)` ? If the result is boolean, replace your if by something like :

```
if isMtEnabled :
  (... body ...)
```

Comment: This `if` would also be true of `isMtEnabled == 'False'`.

Comment: @LutzHorn  **If the result is boolean**

Comment: @IanAuld We don't kow what `isMtEnabled` is. Until the OP gives us this information, guessing that it is a boolean is just guessing, not answering.

Comment: I did try getting the type of isMtEnabled variable. It says its a string - <type 'str'> Also the value of the variable is 'true'. In that case, this condition should work - if isMtEnabled == "true" ??

Comment: Yes if it is a String then this condition should return the value True.

Comment: Are you sure that it's the first if and not the second that failed ? Maybe your first is correct but your second isn't and without else, do nothing

Comment: Yes.. its the first if and its failing.

Comment: So, I don't know how you initialize your dictionary but the value of your boolean is "false". I suggest to you to use a default dict if you want have a "real" control of values. `d = defaultdict(lambda : defaultvalue)`